# Could not find or load main class Main.class in Multi Module Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I have a mulit-module Maven Project (with SpringBoot) where one submodule contains a Main class and the others do not.
Now, when I attempt to start the application I keep getting a `Could not find or load main class Main.class` error.

My folder looks as following:

```
root
\-- Submodule-1
   \-- src
     \-- main
       \-- java
         \-- com.company.package.blabla
           \-- Main.java
\-- Submodule-2
\-- Submodule-3
```

The error appears by using the following command in the `root` directory: `$java com.company.package.blabla.Main` (I also tried it with backslashes instead of fullstops)

Funnily, this command works (while in the root directory): `$java /Users/username/IdeaProjects/Work/projectName/Submodule-1/src/main/java/com/company/package/blabla/Main.java`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `mvn spring-boot:run` , if it is a Spring Boot and Maven Project

Comment: By doing so i get `Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property`. Do I need to add one by chance?

Comment: Just tried that, does not work

Comment: Spring Boot Application is like this : `@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
 }

}`

Comment: `Building Java Projects with Maven` (https://spring.io/guides/gs/maven/)